# How can I restore Start Menu behaviour when clicking folders? (default shell)

Tags: windows, start-menu

I was experimenting with default open handlers for folders (to use an alternative file manager), so messing with HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ *Folder*, *Drive* and *Directory* I was able to change the default *"shell"* handler.

After I was done experimenting I managed to set everything back, except for the taskbar.

This problem affects both the **Start Menu** and the **Quick Launch**: when I click on a folder (shortcut in the Quick Launch) or even the Control Panel, *an explorer window opens up in "Search mode"*.

So, my question is: what I'm missing?
I did a regsvr32 loop to re-register all the DLLs in the windows folder after putting back some default values.

I can simply restore a backup if I want to have the functionality back, so what I'm interested in is discovering how this works behind the scenes.

I'm using Windows XP 32bit, SP3, with classic Start Menu.

Thanks!